# How to using params keyword with [Optional]?

Tags: c#, .net

**How to using params keyword with [Optional]?**
i want to use both keywords params and Optional but it raise error

```
public void m( int x,[Optional] int c,params string [] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("x= {0}", x);        
    foreach (string item in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name ={0}\n",item);
    }
    public static void Main(){
    Program x = new Program();
    x.m(10,"mido","sfs","sgsd"); // here error why?
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: When you call the method, you cannot choose not to give an argument for the optional parameter (`c`) and yet provide an argument for the parameter that follows.

Comment: A better solution would be to use two methods, one with the optional parameter (which will then not be optional) and one without

Comment: Also a possible solution would be to mark the optional parameter only as Nullable. Then you could check that value inside your code

Comment: You have your main-method defined in your `m`-method. This however doesn´t have anything to do with your actual problem, however you shpuld strife towards verifyable examples.

Comment: Basically `params` has to be at the end, and optional cannot be followed by something that isn't optional, otherwise there could be ambiguity.  Based on those rules you cannot use them together.  Instead just create multiple overloads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about that keyword, however if you're passing optional arguments to your class, you need to set the default values. Also, it's key to remember that *optional* parameters **cannot** be followed by *non-optional* parameters. In your example your optional param is followed by a non optional string array.

An example:

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string",
    int optionalint = 10)
```

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: Optional parameters cannot be followed by non-optional parameters that's the issue here.

Comment: @juharr My example contains 3 arguments in the order of required, optional, and optional. Look it over again. It's not even my example. that's straight from MSDN.

Comment: Your example is fine, but note that the OP has a non-optional parameter following an optional one.

Comment: @juharr Oh okay good point. Your initial wording was quite confusing. I've added that to my answer now.